# How to get the specified key value in JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

> console.log(data)

```
{
  "LoginDetails": "{\"BrowserInformation\":\"Mozilla\\/5.0 Chrome\\/76.0.1100.182 Safari\\/537.36\",\"ip_address\":\"180.80.21.172\"}"
}
```

from above object i want to take only the `ip_address`, i don't have idea how to get the value from above object

Comment: `JSON.parse(data. LoginDetails).ip_address`

Comment: or `data.LoginDetails[0].ip_address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(obj)`

```js
var obj={
  "LoginDetails": "{\"BrowserInformation\":\"Mozilla\\/5.0 Chrome\\/76.0.1100.182 Safari\\/537.36\",\"ip_address\":\"180.80.21.172\"}"
};
console.log(JSON.parse(obj.LoginDetails).ip_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(data.LoginDetails).ip_address`. This will give the required value. For other parameters just need to change the name at last.